# Error when using Lidgren Gen3 in Unity3d

Tags: c#, exception, unity-game-engine, mono, lidgren

i have the newest version from Lidgren (gen3) cloned from GitHub and 
i am using Unity3d in the newest version with Mono, but i also tryed
to use Visual Studio 2015.

Everytime i try the compiled DLL from Lidgren in a Unity-Project i got
this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 
The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (bool)
```

Does anyone got a Solution for that?

thx :)

Answer (score 0):

switch Framework version to low. I very bad know english